# Can't create UIButton

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I'm trying to create a button programmatically and make it visible. This is what i do:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

And nothing. It is not visible. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
```

You're creating a button with size 100x100, but not yet adding it to the view.  Then when you do this:

```
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
```

you're making a *new* button, of size 0x0, and still not adding it to the view; the first button will sit around in memory forever.  Then when you do this:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

you're telling the view to bring the new button to the front of the view - but it's not yet on the screen.  What you really wanted to do was this:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

That creates a button, sets up its frame, and then adds it to your view.

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the button to the view.

```
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong. First of all, you create two buttons. You are creating one on the first line, and then creating another on the second line. Also, you need to add the button to your view:

```
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `[self.view addSubview:button];` instead - it will help. Also, you're assigning `*button` twice, so the first one (the one with the frame) will get ignored.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
 [self.view addSubview: button];
```

after your second line.

Also, you're creating 2 buttons - both of your first two lines creates a button.  Pick one!

Answer (score 0):

You are never attaching the button to the main view. My guess is you are confusing `bringSubviewToFront:` with `addSubview`.

```
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the button using

```
[self.view addsubview:button];
```